# Make element the same width as its height

Tags: css

I want to make a div the same width as its height. Currently it stretches horizontally, which is not what I want (see the image). Also have a look at the css code!

Thanks for your advice.

The CSS for the red circle (with the logo):

```
.logo-component {
    background-color: hsla(340, 100%, 50%, 0.6);
    background-image: url('./../images/logo.png');
    background-size: auto calc(100% - 6rem);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 6rem);
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-2.5rem);
}
```

A Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Bye.

Comment: Did you make use of `aspect-ratio`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio

Comment: can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

Use `aspect-ratio` like shown below.

```css
.logo-component {
    background-color: hsla(340, 100%, 50%, 0.6);
    width: 110px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
    resize: horizontal;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-component"></div>
```